# PHP pagination prevent/avoid SQl error or empty pages

Tags: php, pagination

I have a pagination script in PHP which works fine.

If I have a search query it searches the term or if the query is empty it displays all records. So far, so good!

The thing is, if in URL I put 'page=-5', I got a SQL error.
If I have 10 pages and put 'page=11' I got a blank page.

I would like to prevent that.

Like 'page=-5' redirects to 'page=1' and 'page=11' redirects to last page with content.

Here's how I'm doing it:

```
$query = (!empty($_GET['q'])) ? $_GET['q'] : '';

$current_page = (!empty($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page'])) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;

define('registers_pp', 100);
define('pages_range', 5);

$initial_line = ($current_page - 1) * registers_pp;

if (empty($query))
{
    $dataUserUser  = 'SQL getting all user data';
    $countUserUser = 'SQL counting all records';
}
else
{
    $dataUserUser  = 'SQL getting all user data';
    $countUserUser = 'SQL counting all records';
}

$first_page    = 1;
$last_page     = ceil($countUserUser->total / registers_pp);
$previous_page = ($current_page > 1) ? $current_page - 1 : 0;
$next_page     = ($current_page < $last_page) ? $current_page + 1 : 0;
$initial_range = (($current_page - pages_range) >= 1) ? $current_page - pages_range : 1;
$final_range   = (($current_page + pages_range) <= $last_page ) ? $current_page + pages_range : $last_page;
```

I managed to correct part of it, but if I have no records to show, or a query with no result, it becomes a loop.

I tried this:

```
if ($current_page > $last_page)
{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="/user?'.(($query) ? 'q='.$query : '').'&order='.$current_order.'&field='.$current_field.'&page='.$last_page.'";</script>';
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/user?'.(($query) ? 'q='.$query : '').'&order='.$current_order.'&field='.$current_field.'&page='.$last_page.'">';
    exit;
}
elseif ($current_page < 1)
{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="/user?'.(($query) ? 'q='.$query : '').'&order='.$current_order.'&field='.$current_field.'&page=1";</script>';
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/user?'.(($query) ? 'q='.$query : '').'&order='.$current_order.'&field='.$current_field.'&page=1">';
    exit;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't redirect. Instead validate that your values are in the range you support. E.g., `if ($current_page < 1) { $current_page = 1; }`

Comment: For someone going lower than the minimum, that's pretty much guaranteed to be URL hacking (or a bug), so although I'd normally normalize values, too, depending on link canonicalization it might be better to do something more specific. For someone going higher, that could be a cache issue. If those pages are intended to be listed in search engines, it is probably more proper to let them know that the page no longer exists. The UI could in theory stay the same, too, and just a status code changes.